# Tab through a webpage manually

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping, browser-automation

I am trying to navigate through a webpage using just my keyboard. Through the use of my tab key I can enter in data into several input boxes, and press several submit buttons.

However I run into a problem when trying to set focus to an image element on the page. For some reason it does not allow me to select it with the tab key. I can click on it with my mouse and then a popup appears but this really slows down efficiency.

I have considered creating a script in VBA to do this but right now I would prefer a quick-fix without having to spend hours developing a macro.

**NOTE:** I did quickly try to assign the reference to the `<img>` element and use the `Click` and `Focus` methods in VBA but that didn't work. I don't get an error, the code runs fine but nothing happens on the webpage. This leads me to think that this will be a bigger project than it appears, hence my reluctance to go down that path.

I did a bit of research and it seems that `tabindex` is not supported by the `<img>` element. Does that mean what I am trying to accomplish is impossible with the keyboard? Is code my only option?

If anyone knows anything that could help in VBA by all means I will take your advice into consideration.

Unfortunately the webpage is password protected and its a company account therefore I cannot post it.

After right-clicking inspect element in my `Chrome` browser this is what I see:

```
<img alt="View Quantities At Other Locations" src="/WebOrder/Images/CheckQtys.gif" 
 title="View Quantities At Other Locations" class="popup"popupdirection="upperleft" 
 popupwidth="380" popupcontent="#ProductQuantitiesForAccessibleBranches" 
 onbeforepopupcreate="onBeforePopupCreate_GetProductQuantitiesForAccessibleBranches(this)" 
 popupajaxformid="GetProductQuantitiesForAccessibleBranches" 
 onbeforepopupajaxpost="onBeforePopupAjaxPost_GetProductQuantitiesForAccessibleBranches(this)" 
 oncompletepopupajaxpost="onCompletePopupAjaxPost_GetProductQuantitiesForAccessibleBranches(this)" 
 productguid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000058927" displayitem="732899500" 
 brandguid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" brandname="" brandsku="">
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can set focus to this element (either with my keyboard or VBA)?

Comment: Try something like `ie.document.getElementsByTagName("img")(0).focus`, where 0 is the Index of the Img tag on the website.

Comment: hmm, interesting. I tried `.getElementsByClassName` before I posted this question. Now I also tried your method but it doesn't work either. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @RyanWildry Do you think I need to fire some javascript event before the click? The problem is that all the attributes are `Null` in my locals window so I don't know which one to even try...

Comment: Can you post the website's URL? Keep in mind, you might need to change the index from 0 as it may not be the first item in the collection.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. The item number is not a problem. I ran a for loop through all the item numbers so I'm 100% sure.

Comment: Did you check all frames/iframes as well? This image should be in the collection with all other img tags.

Comment: You know I think you're onto something Ryan! I checked the page from top to bottom and all the frames are at the bottom. I've identified the one I want to interact with. `<form id="GetProductQuantitiesForAccessibleBranches" action="GetProductQuantitiesForAccessibleBranches" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="ProductGuid" value="a12e3324-bb08-e611-91c5-005056a21dde">
</form>` I will try the `Forms.Submit` method, using the `ProductGuid` value from the image tag prior to submit.

Comment: Well @RyanWildry sadly no luck. I tired changing the value of the input element inside the form and then submitting it but it still does nothing. I also tried clicking on the image element again after I changed the form value, but this still does the same thing. My code runs fine, but nothing happens on the page.

Comment: The form or the frame? I was talking about the frame. The element might be in a different frame, which would explain why it wasn't enumerated by `getElementsByTagName`. You may need to iterate over each frame, looking for the `img` tag in question.

Comment: There are no frame tags on the page. There are even comments in the HTML code: "//This page should never load inside of a frame/frameset ..."
But you did set me on the right course. I'm still not quite there. Maybe you can help [New Question]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111278/form-submit-does-not-go-through-when-using-vba Lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121672/discussion-between-theguyoverthere-and-ryan-wildry).

Answer (score 0):

You can focus on a div using `<div tabindex=0> Stuff Here </div>`. Place the image inside the div and use the div to manipulate it.

Comment: I wish I could. I actually saw something similar on here before I typed my question. The company has an account on the website, but does not own the website. Therefore I cannot change any HTML code. Thanks anyways though!